# SCORM 1.2 suspended_data for different SCOs

Tags: scorm

I'm new to SCORM itself and I have a problem with tracking progress via Moodle's LMS API

SCORM version is 1.2

I have structure like this:

Lesson1

- Module1.1
- Module1.2

...

Lesson2

- Module 2.1

etc

Each lesson has a set of modules of 2 types:

HTML Modules - modules that are just viewed by users

Game Modules - some games that have a medal (none, bronez, silver, gold) - as a result of module completness

The progress tracking problem is following:

I need to track progress on different Lessons based on a progress of their children Modules (sequencing?).

After all: I need to add a START to a lesson after all Game modules of the lesson are finished. Star indicates some sort of Progress on a lesson level

What I'm trying to do is to store Module's progress data (medals) in cmi.suspended_data variable as a string:

"module1.1,gold|module1.2|silver ..."

After that I want to process that thing each time page is loaded and figure out if I gain a STAR to one of lessons. For example: when I've finished last game in lesson1 with a medal so that all games are now have medals - and after that I move to lesson 2 -  I should add star to lesson 1...

The problem is that moving from module to module and from lesson to module etc - RESETS suspended_data variable.

Question1: Does suspended data link to a SCO object? (which means each module/lesson has it's own suspended_data var)

Question2: What is CORRECT approach in this situation to trach sequencing progress (As I've seen, scorm 2004 has some sequencing mechanisms that can be described in Manifest. Which is correct approach in 1.2 version)

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: the cmi.suspend_data is unique to each SCO, and can only be read/set from within the SCO. In your case, SCO2 cannot read SCO1's suspend_data and vice-versa.

Question 2: you'd better stick with a single SCO aproach here. All your modules and lesson will be part of a single SCO, which means you will be able to track the medals and user progress w/o any problem.